# Image load in Desktop Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

```
let img1 = document.createElement('img'); 
img1.setAttribute('src', 'https://caniuse.com/img/browserstack.svg');
```

I have created an `<img>` without inserting into the document, then I executed `setAttribute(src, '')` and the resource was loaded immediately; I want to load the resource when `<img>` is inserted into the document. What can I do?

Comment: you want what ?

Comment: @KakulSarma I do not want <img> to load src when <img> is not inserted into the document

Comment: Check The answer and inform me if you have any issue

Comment: are you talking about lazyLoader

Comment: @KakulSarma Thanks, the answer I want

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the img tag inside a [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) tag.

```
var tpl = document.createElement('template')
tpl.innerHTML = '<img>'
var img = tpl.content.querySelector('img')
// won't prefetch the image
img.src = 'https://caniuse.com/img/browserstack.svg'
```

Comment: @刘江宇 see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do when someone answers